# How to filter JSON data by properties that contain certain strings?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON Object that looks like this:

```
{
  'name': 'Bob',
  'friends': [
    {
      'name' : 'Ashley (Family)'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'Steven (Non-Family)'
    },
    {
      'name' : 'Chris (Family)'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter the above, so that it returns only the friends that are family? i.e. friends who's name contains '(Family)'?

```
function filterFriends (friends) {

  return friends.filter(function(i) {
    if (i.name.indexOf('(Family)') > -1) {
      return i.name;
    }
  });

}
```

But the above doesn't seem to work... I don't know if I'm on the right track?

Comment: replace `return i.name` with `return true`

Comment: You say it doesn't seem to work, what are you seeing?

Comment: seems to be [working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/m3b2k2br/)

Comment: Please explain why you think it *" doesn't seem to work"*. Voting to close since it is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than **a)** using the phrase "JSON Object" which makes no sense and **b)** relying on sloppy automatic casting of booleans, you really don't have a problem. This "answer", with minor technical improvements will demonstrate that your code is just fine.

```
var data = {
  name: 'Bob',
  friends: [
    {
      name: 'Ashley (Family)'
    },
    {
      name: 'Steven (Non-Family)'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris (Family)'
    }
  ]
};

var family = data.friends.filter(f => f.name.indexOf('(Family)') > -1);

console.log(family);
// [{name: 'Ashley (Family)'}, {name: 'Chris (Family)'}]
```

If you want to write it into a function

```
function isFamily(name) {
  return name.indexOf('(Family)') > -1;
}

function getFamily(friends) {
  return friends.filter(f => isFamily(f.name));
}

var family = getFamily(data.friends);
```

**ES5**

```
var family = data.friends.filter(function(f) {
  return f.name.indexOf('(Family)') > -1);
});

console.log(family);
```

Comment: Your way is exactly the same as OP's way, did you try to understand his problem?

Comment: @Motti sorry but you don't know what the word "exact" means.

Comment: @TJ if by "same" you mean my code also uses an `if` and relies upon strings being automatically cast to `true` and `undefined` being cast to `false`, then sure, the answers are the "same" - I don't see either though.

Comment: They are semantically equivalent, you use true and false while he uses truthy and falsely and you use a different syntax for lambda functions. But in essence they are the same

Comment: Yes it automatically casts to true/false and it does work. OP didn't ask for a solution with micro improvement. You posted a solution to a *problem* which doesn't exist.

Comment: Both of your egos are too big that you'd rather promote a sloppy practice than admit you don't have anything useful to add here. At the very least, you're down-voting an answer that clearly demonstrates there *isn't* a problem.

Comment: @maček people like you are promoting crappy questions trying to be the fastest gun without even checking whether there is a problem. As a reputed member, if you think there is no problem you should comment the same and close the question rather than trying to farm rep from everything you see

Answer (score 0):

Filter method should always return boolean value, this looks like returning always the string with the name.

Take a look to docs for .filter method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: It doesn't have to. JavaScript truthy/falsy will be just fine.

Comment: That's false, only on his condition is he returning true, if it fails then the function returns with undefined, which is false.

Comment: @Konrad, I agree with you that it *should* always return a boolean. Relying on truthiness is sloppy, in my opinion.